# How to modify a .pd file from python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a .pd file called 'missing' on my computer. The path is C:\me\Desktop\missing.pd

Inside this file there is just dates. I have an algo which create and populate this 'missing.pd' with dates everytime I run it. My algo basically create a dataframe with inside some dates, sometime empty and then create the missing.pd file on my computer and add the dates. 
 What I am trying to do is to not recreate everytime the missing.pd file (that's what my code do so far).

I want to say to my code :

if C:\me\Desktop\missing.pd exist, then check inside if the dates of my created dataframe are already here, if no add the ones which are not already here, if missing.pd do not exist, create it and fill it with the dates.

so far for this part of the code, it is :

```
path = r"C:\me\Desktop\missing.pd"
missing = pd.DataFrame(missing)
missing.to_pickle( os.path.join(path,"%s_missing.pd"%(country)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.path.isfile(filename)` to check if the file exists.  Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile).

```
import os.path
if os.path.isfile(path):
    """Your date checking code here."""
```